# How to make ajax calls to different MVC controllers

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm getting error 404 while making ajax calls to my MVC controller

Here is the scenario:

I have 2 controllers:(PartnerControler,GettingSartedController)

While on the getting started page:`http://mysite/GettingStarted/` I make the following ajax call:

```
$scope.SubmitRegistration = function() {
  return $http({
    url: '/partner/register',
    method: 'POST',
    data: $scope.UserAccount,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
```

I get a 404 on the call to the controller.

when I add the exact register method to the gettingstarted controller and change the ajax URL to the following it works:

```
url: '/gettingstarted/register',
```

When on web a page that uses a specific controller can you make calls to another controller?

How can this be achieved modifying the above script?

Comment: Can you access the `partner/register` via the browser address bar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have separate js files, you can use workaround like below

```
<input type="hidden" id="registerurl" data-register-url="@Url.Action("register", "partner")"/>
```

and use this `element's attribute` as `url` to be used in your `http` call

```
var urlRegisterPartner = $('#registerurl').data('register-url');
```

Comment: whats the difference between doing this and specifying the exact Url

Comment: Please check using debugger, whats the value of urlRegisterPartner.

Answer (score 0):

I found another very good answer here in
https://stackoverflow.com/a/57274117/14181068 for
[Ajax call to a different controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57274065/ajax-call-to-a-different-controller)

This is the summary i got from the answer.

| url on ajax | result |
| --- | --- |
| your/path | `http://example.com/Home/your/path` |
| ~/your/path | `http://example.com/Home/~/your/path or http://example.com/your/path` |
| .../your/path | `http://example.com/Home/.../your/path` |
| ../your/path | `go up one directory level, resulting in http://example.com/your/path.` |
| /your/path | `http://example.com/your/path` |

sample

```js
        $.ajax({
            type: 'Get',
            url: "YourUrlHere",
            data: { id: $('#inputId').val() },
        })
        .done(function (response) {
            if (response.length > 0) {                
            }
        })
        .fail(function (error) {
            alert(error.StatusText);
        });
```